# rolling moving average and std dev by multiple columns dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Country':['UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','US','US','US','US','US','US'],
    'Product':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D'],
            'Week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
       'val': [5,4,3,1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country','Product','Week', 'val'])

print(df2)
```

i want to calculate moving average and std dev for val column by country and product..like 3 weeks,5 weeks ,7 weeks etc

wanted dataframe:

'Contry', 'product','week',val', '3wks_avg' '3wks_std','5wks_avg',5wks,std'..etc

Comment: check with for loop  and groupby rolling ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like WenYoBen suggested, we can create a list of all the window sizes you want, and then dynamically create your wanted columns with [`GroupBy.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
weeks = [3, 5, 7]

for week in weeks:
    df[[f'{week}wks_avg', f'{week}wks_std']] = (
        df.groupby(['Country', 'Product']).rolling(window=week, on='Week')['val']
          .agg(['mean', 'std']).reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

```
   Country Product  Week  val  3wks_avg  3wks_std  5wks_avg  5wks_std  7wks_avg  7wks_std
0       UK       A     1    5       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
1       UK       A     2    4       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
2       UK       A     3    3      4.00      1.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
3       UK       A     4    1      2.67      1.53       nan       nan       nan       nan
4       UK       B     1    5       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
5       UK       B     2    6       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
6       UK       B     3    7      6.00      1.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
7       UK       B     4    8      7.00      1.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
8       UK       B     5    9      8.00      1.00      7.00      1.58       nan       nan
9       UK       B     6   10      9.00      1.00      8.00      1.58       nan       nan
10      UK       B     7   11     10.00      1.00      9.00      1.58      8.00      2.16
11      UK       B     8   12     11.00      1.00     10.00      1.58      9.00      2.16
12      UK       C     1    5       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
13      UK       C     2    5       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
14      UK       C     3    5      5.00      0.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
15      US       D     1    5       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
16      US       D     2    6       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan       nan
17      US       D     3    7      6.00      1.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
18      US       D     4    8      7.00      1.00       nan       nan       nan       nan
19      US       D     5    9      8.00      1.00      7.00      1.58       nan       nan
20      US       D     6   10      9.00      1.00      8.00      1.58       nan       nan
```

Comment: This method is amazingly concise and returns the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would get the moving average for 3 weeks :

```
df['3weeks_avg'] = list(df.groupby(['Country', 'Product']).rolling(3).mean()['val'])
```

Apply the same principle for the other columns you want to compute.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you may try this

```
wks = ['Week_3', 'Week_5', 'Week_7']

df_calc = (df2.groupby(['Country', 'Product']).expanding().val
              .agg(['mean', 'std']).rename(lambda x: f'Week_{x+1}', level=-1)
              .query('ilevel_2 in @wks').unstack())

Out[246]:
                  mean                  std
                Week_3 Week_5 Week_7 Week_3 Week_5 Week_7
Country Product
UK      A          4.0    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN
        B          NaN    5.0    6.0    NaN    NaN    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a groupby-transform to get the rolling moments of your data. The following should compute what you are looking for:

```
weeks = [3, 5, 7] # define weeks
df2 = df2.sort_values('Week') # order by time
for i in weeks: # loop through time intervals you want to compute
    df2['{}wks_avg'.format(i)] = df2.groupby(['Country', 'Product'])['val'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(i).mean()) # i-week rolling mean
    df2['{}wks_std'.format(i)] = df2.groupby(['Country', 'Product'])['val'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(i).std()) # i-week rolling std
```

Here is what the resulting dataframe will look like.

```
print(df2.dropna().head().to_string())
   Country Product  Week  val  3wks_avg  3wks_std  5wks_avg  5wks_std  7wks_avg  7wks_std
17      US       D     3    7       6.0       1.0       6.0       1.0       6.0       1.0
6       UK       B     3    7       6.0       1.0       6.0       1.0       6.0       1.0
14      UK       C     3    5       5.0       0.0       5.0       0.0       5.0       0.0
2       UK       A     3    3       4.0       1.0       4.0       1.0       4.0       1.0
7       UK       B     4    8       7.0       1.0       7.0       1.0       7.0       1.0
```